# How do I make a Wizard control save the data after each step?

Tags: asp.net, wizard-control

Is there a way that i can save data on each step in wizard control.
I want to save data when user clicks next button on each step.
I would like to save them to database , so that i can retrieve them back if user has opted to close and complete steps later without clicking finish button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save data to Session or ViewState objects.

Also you can add you saving logic in wizard events: ActiveStepChanged, CancelButtonClick, FinishButtonClick, NextButtonClick, PreviousButtonClick, SideBarButtonClick.

Answer (score 2):

In your code-behind, you can capture the "Active Step Changed" event and do whatever you want:

```
Protected Sub AddEmployeeWizard_ActiveStepChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddEmployeeWizard.ActiveStepChanged

  'save your data here

End Sub
```

If you just want to save on a click of the Next button, you could instead do

```
Protected Sub myWizard_NextButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles myWizard.NextButtonClick

    'save your data here

End Su
```

b

Comment: i would like 2 save data when clicked next button, this event will fire for both next, previous. Is there a way i can distinguish each ?

Comment: Edited to add an example of saving on a Next click.

Comment: yes that is correct answer, i tested it and it works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET you can probably stick it in the Session variable.

In an WPF or Winforms app, you could just put it in a variable in memory, and if these are settings for your program, you could save them to an XML file.

Comment: i would like to save each step, bcos user may close browser and complete them later